# Why do I get an error about non-exhaustive patterns?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I'm writing a chat server using [mio](https://docs.rs/mio/0.5.1/mio/) (0.5.1), following [this tutorial](https://nbaksalyar.github.io/2015/07/10/writing-chat-in-rust.html). With it, I have written the following Handler:

```
const SERVER_TOKEN: Token = Token(0);

impl Handler for WebSocketServer {
    type Timeout = usize;
    type Message = ();

    fn ready(&mut self, event_loop: &mut EventLoop<WebSocketServer>,
             token: Token, events: EventSet)
    {
        match token {
            SERVER_TOKEN => {
                let client_socket = match self.socket.accept() {
                    Err(e) => {
                        println!("Accept error: {}", e);
                        return;
                    },
                    Ok(None) => unreachable!("Accept has returned 'None'"),
                    Ok(Some((sock, addr))) => sock,
                };

                self.token_counter += 1;
                let new_token = Token(self.token_counter);

                self.clients.insert(new_token, client_socket);
                event_loop.register(&self.clients[&new_token],
                                    new_token, EventSet::readable(),
                                    PollOpt::edge() | PollOpt::oneshot()).unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, in trying to compile it I get an error:

```
error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `Token(_)` not covered
  --> src/main.rs:23:15
   |
23 |         match token {
   |               ^^^^^ pattern `Token(_)` not covered

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Although I understand that this should mean that my `match` does not cover all possible cases, I do not see how  that is true.

Why am I getting this error, and how may I fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here `SERVER_TOKEN` is a constant equal to `Token(0)`, so let's simplify the match:

```
match token {
    Token(0) => { },
}
```

While *you* know that you won't get any other tokens, the compiler doesn't know, and the type allows other values like `Token(1)`.  You can add a case to cover the other cases, and just `panic`.  I like to print out what was matched if it ever does happen as a debug aid.

```
match token {
    SERVER_TOKEN => { },
    x => panic!("Unexpected invalid token {:?}", x),
}
```

This assumes that `Token` implements `Debug`.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing on your second bit of code. What is `x`? Also, why is the `SERVER_TOKEN` match terminated in a simple colon?

Comment: `x` is just a dummy name which mathes anything.  I can't see a colon (did you mean the comma?); I left out all the handling that's not relevant to the question to make the example shorter.

Comment: Yeah, I meant, comma, not sure why I wrote colon. I see what you mean now, thanks for taking the time to help me :)